# Rails 5.2.1 - Model & Fragment Caching

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, memorycache, fragment-caching

I am trying to setup Model and Fragment Caching in Rails 5.2.1

I have had success with Fragment caching, but I am still seeing database queries after implementing model caching for my Model.

I have enabled development caching

```
$ rails dev:cache
```

**Model Helper**

```
module LanguagesHelper
  def approved_languages
    Rails.cache.fetch("approved_languages") { Languages.is_active.is_approved }
  end
end
```

**Controller**

```
class LanguagesController < ApplicationController
  include LanguagesHelper

  def index
    @languages = approved_languages
  end
end
```

**Views**

*app/views/languages/index.html.erb*

```
<%= render partial: 'languages/language', collection: @languages, cached: true %>
```

*app/views/languages/_language.html.erb*

```
<% cache language do %>
  <%= language.name %>
<% end %>
```

**Console**

```
Started GET "/languages" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-08-21 14:13:29 -0400
Processing by LanguagesController#index as HTML
  Rendering languages/index.html.erb within layouts/application
  Language Load (1.2ms)  SELECT "languages".* FROM "languages" WHERE "languages"."deleted" = $1 AND "languages"."approved" = $2  [["deleted", false], ["approved", true]]
  ↳ app/views/languages/index.html.erb:4
  Rendered collection of languages/_language.html.erb [1 / 1 cache hits] (3.0ms)
  Rendered languages/index.html.erb within layouts/application (10.9ms)
Completed 200 OK in 50ms (Views: 46.2ms | ActiveRecord: 1.2ms)
```

Why am I still seeing database queries with each request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was close before but now have successfully implemented caching. The above answer was appreciated but not what I was looking for, this is my current setup.

I was calling the Language model query in a Helper module when I should have moved it to the model.

**Model**

```
after_save :clear_cache
after_destroy :clear_cache

def clear_language_cache
  Rails.cache.delete('Language.active.approved')
end

def self.active_approved
  Rails.cache.fetch('Language.active.approved') { is_active.is_approved.order(created_at: :desc).to_a }
end
```

**Controller**

```
class LanguagesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @languages = Language.active_approved
  end
end
```

**Console**

```
Started GET "/languages" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-08-22 18:13:21 -0400
Processing by LanguagesController#index as HTML
  Rendering languages/index.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered collection of languages/_language.html.erb [1 / 1 cache hits] (11.0ms)
  Rendered languages/index.html.erb within layouts/application (15.9ms)
Completed 200 OK in 68ms (Views: 45.5ms | ActiveRecord: 5.8ms)
```

Answer (score 2):

What seems to be going on here is that you're caching the relation *before* it loads the records, and so it still has to actually load them before it can be used (using my Ad model because it's there and convenient for testing in irb):

```
ads = Ad.all;nil # no query here, this is what I think you're caching
# this next line is where the query is run, (this would be
# equivalent to your render line)
ads.each { ... } 
#  Ad Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "ads".* FROM "ads"
```

instead you might try forcing active record to load the relation before you cache it and see if that helps. You can do this by using [`load`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/load):

```
ads = Ad.all.load;nil # query is now run here
#  Ad Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "ads".* FROM "ads"
ads.each { ... } # and not run here
```

and together with caching enabled (all in a single rails console session, multiple sessions seems to forget the cache from the previous, but I've not configured caching so probably just an in-memory store of some kind)

```
ads = Rails.cache.fetch("test load") { Ad.all.load };nil # query
#  Ad Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "ads".* FROM "ads"
ads = Rails.cache.fetch("test load") { Ad.all.load };nil # no query
ads.each {  } # no query
ads = Rails.cache.fetch("test without load") { Ad.all };nil # no query
ads.each { };nil # query
#  Ad Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "ads".* FROM "ads"
ads = Rails.cache.fetch("test without load") { Ad.all };nil # no query
ads.each { };nil # query
#  Ad Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "ads".* FROM "ads"
```